# why routes with % character in routes will display blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in rails when the routes or url has % will display blank page.

e.g www.domain.com/% ---- will display blank page

I check also some website like github.com/% but still display in blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). In short.

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted
>   over the Internet.

Then we have some basic terminology you might wish to know

**URL - Uniform Resource Locator**

> Web browsers request pages from web servers by using a URL.
>   The URL is the address of a web page, like https://stackoverflow.com/

**URL Encoding (Percent Encoding)**

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding **replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%"** followed by
>   **two hexadecimal digits**. URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding
>   normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Well, so when your route contains only `%`, it was recognized as the encoded string but it missed **two hexadecimal digits** followed so you will always get a blank page or a custom error page depends on how your site was configured.
Because browser will request to `https://stackoverflow.com/%` and it is not existing.

---

**How to handle it**

Basically, If your URL is in unwell format when requesting to the server. It will return you an `HTTP 400 error code` which means

> [10.4.1 400 Bad Request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

So what we need to do is just doing configuration on the server to redirect to a custom error page (in this case IIS Web Server of ASP.NET website). Example can found [here](http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/)

Comment: it's a good explanation about how url works. but i want to handle it gracefully in rails so I can display 404 pages. like what in `http://stackoverflow.com/%` it display `Bad Request - Invalid URL` message but when you try `https://github.com/%` it will display blank page.

Comment: @XanderDwyl I have updated the answer with an example for .NET application since I am not a ruby developer. Hope you can get the idea.